# The CodeDeploy got failed when the local airflow.cfg is packaged in zip file

Tags: airflow, aws-code-deploy

I tried to deploy airflow DAGs to AWS EC2. I followed the instruction on [aws-airflow-stack](https://github.com/villasv/aws-airflow-stack). The airflow runs well on EC2. 
In EC2 Instances, there are two airflow.cfg files, they are located at:

```
/airflow/airflow.cfg
/home/ec2-user/airflow/airflow.cfg
```

In folder '/airflow', the Dags data existed there. 
In folder '/home/ec2-user/airflow', it just has airflow.cfg, airflow.db, logs and unittests.cfg files. Both with the default settings.

Now I need to add some users on Postgers database, I put the [webserver] authenticate = true and rbac = true in my local airflow.cfg, and deploy this config file with CodeDeploy, the deployment got failed. Check the log, In install event. the message is
" The deployment failed because a specified file already exists at this location: /airflow/airflow.cfg". 
How do I address this issue? how to deploy a local airflow config file to EC2? Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Can you also provide the command you used to trigger CodeDeploy?

The command in the [example Makefile](https://github.com/villasv/aws-airflow-stack/blob/master/src/Makefile) specifies that files already existing should be overwritten:

```
aws deploy create-deployment \
    --application-name $(APPLICATION) \
    --deployment-group-name $(DEPLOYMENT_GROUP) \
    --s3-location bucket=$(DEPLOYMENTS_BUCKET),bundleType=tgz,key=$(PACKAGE) \
    --deployment-config-name CodeDeployDefault.AllAtOnce \
    --file-exists-behavior OVERWRITE
```

Special attention to the `--file-exists-behavior OVERWRITE` part. Using the Makefile to deploy will ensure your `airflow.cfg` file will replace the existing one.

Comment: Awesome!, the '--file-exists-behavior ' fixed the issue . Thank you.